# Why is AppleScript not ejecting my volume?

Tags: applescript, eject

I have a hard drive in my mac with multiple partitions, and I want to eject some of them with AppleScript. Simple:

```
tell application "Finder" 
    eject disk "Photos"
end tell
```

Except it does not work. I can eject the drive from Disk Utility no problem; here it is right after ejecting:

[image]

So the question is, how do I debug this situation — what could be going wrong?

Comment: Does the AppleScript return any sort of error, or does it fail silently? Does it fail when you run it through the Script Editor? How are you running it?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. The Finder command eject seems to be unable to eject volumes although according to what I found on the internet it worked in times from 10.4 to 10.6.

The following script works. I have saved is as an Application in the Script Editor and have added it as a start object. Works well in my case.

```
tell application "Finder"
    set d to disk "Photos"

    if (exists d) then
        say "Disk exists"
    else
        say "Disk does not exist"
    end if
    if (d is local volume) then
        say "Disk is a local volume"
    else
        say "Disk is not a local volume"
    end if

    if (d is ejectable) then
        say "Disk is ejectable"
    else
        say "Disk is not ejectable"
    end if

    -- This fails because the disk is not ejectable
    eject d
end tell

-- Solution: Use Disk Utility directly
tell application "Terminal"
    do shell script "d=\"/Volumes/Photos\"; if [ -d \"$d\" ]; then diskutil eject $d; fi"
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

Someone posted this and when I reloaded the page it was gone! Not sure why: seems to work!:

```
diskutil eject "/Volumes/Photos"
```

This is a shell script, not an AppleScript, but since I'm triggering it in Keyboard Maestro, it's just as good.